# Hide path on frontpage redirect

Tags: 9, event-subscribers

In a custom module i'm using an `EventSubscriber` to redirect different people to different frontpages. Below is the simplified code I'm using.

```
//GET PATH
$nid = 1;
$domain_url = \Drupal::service('path_alias.manager')->getAliasByPath('/node/'. $nid);

//FRONTPAGE REDIRECT
$response = new RedirectResponse($domain_url);
$event->setResponse($response);
```

The module is working but there is one detail I can't seem to solve.

For example on my website `domain.com` I have `node/1` that has an alias path `/home`.

When going to `domain.com` it is, because of my module as expected, redirected to `domain.com/home`. But what I want is the url not to show the `home` part. Is it possible to show the content of `/home` but keeping the url `domain.com`?

Comment: If you don't want to change the URL in the browser then don't redirect. From the event subscriber you could start a sub request. Or change the incoming path in path processing. For the latter @Jaypan has developed a solution by making path processing domain aware. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/288321/is-there-a-way-to-partially-rebuild-the-router-or-invalidate-a-route-cache

Comment: What @Jaypan has done...is exactly what I need but I can't figure out (by the post) what he did. It doesn't look like the full code. I'll try and figure out how path processing is working..

Comment: For *I've overriden Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteProvider::getRouteCollectionCacheId()* see https://www.bounteous.com/insights/2017/04/19/drupal-how-override-core-drupal-8-service/

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using large parts of the PathProcessorFront.php from core to get my module to work. Only thing is that I have a caching problem I'll create a new post for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the path to your homepage from admin/config/system/site-information

And replace /node/1 to /home.

You don't need an even subscriber to do that.

Comment: I know the default way of setting the frontpage. I'm working with a custom module to be able to set multiple frontpages.

Comment: I would rather have one frontpage which would serve the content dynamically even if it needs multiple rules to load it and keep the default way of setting the frontpage.