# Disable caching for a front page path processor

Tags: caching, path-aliases, 9

I’m working on a project where users can create a book (core functionality). In a simple text field they can connect a domain to this book. This way the book is only accessible via this domain.

For example I have `Book A` with path `node\1` and with domain `a.book.com`. I also have `Book B` with path `node\2` and connected to domain `b.book.com`.

What I want now is if a visitor goes to `a.book.com` the frontpage is `node/1`. And if they go to `b.book.com` the frontpage should be `node/2`? I created a custom module for this `book_frontpage`.

For this I used large parts of the `PathProcessorFront.php` from core.

The code of my `book_front.services.yml` is:

```
services:
  book_frontpage.path_processor_front:
    class: Drupal\book_frontpage\PathProcessor\FrontPagePathProcessor
    tags:
      - { name: path_processor_inbound, priority: 300 }
```

The code of my `FrontPagePathProcessor.php` is:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\book_frontpage\PathProcessor;

use Drupal\Core\Database\Database;
use Drupal\Core\PathProcessor\InboundPathProcessorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

/**
 * Path processor to replace 'node' with 'content' in URLs.
 */
class FrontPagePathProcessor implements InboundPathProcessorInterface{
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function processInbound($path, Request $request)
  {
    if ($path === '/') {
      //current domain
      $currentDomain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

      //get nid of reader where domain is set
      $nid = Database::getConnection()->select('node__field_domain', 'd')
        ->fields('d', ['entity_id'])
        ->condition('field_domain_value', $currentDomain, '=')
        ->execute()
        ->fetchField();

      //get path
      $path = \Drupal::service('path_alias.manager')->getAliasByPath('/node/'. $nid);

      if (empty($path)) {
        // We have to return a valid path but / won't be routable and config
        // might be broken so stop execution.
        throw new NotFoundHttpException();
      }
      $components = parse_url($path);

      // Remove query string and fragment.
      $path = $components['path'];

      // Merge query parameters from front page configuration value
      // with URL query, so that actual URL takes precedence.
      if (!empty($components['query'])) {
        parse_str($components['query'], $parameters);
        array_replace($parameters, $request->query->all());
        $request->query->replace($parameters);
      }
    }

    return $path;
  }
}
```

Now when going to `a.book.com` I see `node/1` but when I go to `b.book.com` I also see `node/1`.  When I clear cache and first go to `b.book.com` I get `node/2` but when going to `a.book.com` I also get `node/2`. So this looks like a cache problem.

How can I disable caching of this front page path?

Comment: So you're not using the [Domain Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) family of modules? Assigning content to different domains, and everything related to that, is their whole deal.

Comment: No I find the domain module to big and complex to use for my users who need to be able to add their domain themselves. Now the only thing they have to do is fill in the field and they are done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed here, [Hide path on frontpage redirect](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/298167/hide-path-on-frontpage-redirect), you need to make caching of route collections domain-specific. Other than the discussed overriding of the core service, since Drupal 8.8 you can use the service method [addExtraCacheKeyPart()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Routing%21CacheableRouteProviderInterface.php/function/CacheableRouteProviderInterface%3A%3AaddExtraCacheKeyPart/9.0.x).

Add this code in a request event subscriber:

*/src/EventSubscriber/RouteCacheDomainSubscriber.php*

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class RouteCacheDomainSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {
  
  public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event) {
    $routeProvider = \Drupal::service('router.route_provider');
    $domain = \Drupal::request()->getHost();
    $routeProvider->addExtraCacheKeyPart('domain', $domain);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    // run before RouterListener (priority 32)
    $events[KernelEvents::REQUEST][] = ['onKernelRequest', 33];
    return $events;
  }

}
```

*mymodule.services.yml*

```
services:
  mymodule.route_cache_domain_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\mymodule\EventSubscriber\RouteCacheDomainSubscriber
    arguments: []
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

Also, you need to invalidate the cache tag `route_match` when book nodes are saved. See [Is there a way to partially rebuild the router or invalidate a route cache?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/288321/is-there-a-way-to-partially-rebuild-the-router-or-invalidate-a-route-cache)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes I created a new post because this was clearly a different question and I still didn't know what to do. I work now.

Only thing I did was changing `GetResonseEvent` to `RequestEvent` and changing `use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;` to `use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;` to remove the deprecated GetResponseEvent class.

Comment: About your last remark, is this invalidating is necessary for when the path alias changes? And is it possible to solve this by not using the alias path but the default path to the node 'node/1'?

Comment: Sorry, I see now that all content is cached... I'll try and figure it out with the link you gave. Thanks!

Comment: On path alias changes the `route_match` tag is invalidated automatically. This is core behavior. For this specific custom path processing, which depends on a node field, you need to invalidate the cache tag in custom code when the node is submitted so that when you change the field content the route is matched again. Whether you use node/1 or alias doesn't matter because your path processor runs before aliasing. The only advantage, if you change the alias every time you change the node, you don't need custom code to invalidate the cache tag.

Comment: If you render content depending on the domain add the cache context `url.site`. For example in preprocess: `$variables['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'url.site';`

Comment: Concerning the event classes. Change the event class only if you don't need code compatibility with Drupal 8. My code runs in D8 & D9, your code in D9 & D10.

Comment: I tried to add the `$variables['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'url.site';` to a page preprocess in my module but this doesn't seem to work. I think the `hook_preprocess_page` only works in a .theme file.

It tried figuring it out with other questions concerning this issue. But I'm not getting there. The redirecting works perfectly but content of the page is still cached.

Comment: Module or theme doesn't matter, but you need to add the cache context to any element depending on the domain, for example nodes or blocks.