# What's the easiest way to dynamically set <front> on a per request basis?

Tags: 8

I need to be able to set the front page based on the current language (derived from domain) and brand (also derived from domain).

I initially tried to set this up with views, but I need the front page to be rendered as a "real" node - and not as a view. This is because the rendering of the page header and footer depends on the node being viewed. So this did not work as expected.

What is the easiest way on a **per request basis** to set the internal path which e.g.  should resolve to?

Comment: You need a path processor, but caching is a bit tricky. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/298257/disable-caching-for-a-front-page-path-processor

Comment: @4k4 thanks, that worked!